# strange terminal output when using colour/style formatting

Tags: python, terminal, formatting

I have the code:

```
import sys
for i in range(0, 20):
  for j in range(0, 20):
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1;32;40m' + '  ' + '\x1b[0m')
  sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

which outputs 400 white squares in a 20x20 grid but also after about 180 squares outputs `[1;32;40m` in between some of the squares. It doesn't always output in the same place. Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try to use `print` or `sys.stdout.write`, not both. Depending on how your terminal buffers there might be different effects.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect on this particular issue

Comment: On what terminal / operating system is this failing on ?

Comment: https://repl.it

Answer (score 0):

It's *probably* caused by some buffering bug in the terminal (I guess).
I can't replicate your issue, so here are some suggestions.

Output to sys.stdout is buffered. You could try flushing the output after each line of text ~

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

But a better solution might be to add the bunch of escape codes to a string, then write it in a block ~

```
import sys

colour_line = '\x1b[1;32;40m' + ('  ' * 20) + '\x1b[0m' + '\n'
for i in range(0, 20):
    sys.stdout.write(colour_line)
```

This obviously simplifies the code, but this is getting away from your original design.

Comment: Your second solution works with squares up to size 170 (as opposed to 16 previously), but in my code I'm not making the entire line the same colour

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but

`time.sleep(0.0005)`

or a different adjusted time between each print seems to work